# Login screen - clicking one user account selects another when multiple in use

Tags: macbook-pro, login-screen

I have multiple user accounts and often am logged into two at a time on my Macbook Pro. Sometimes when I am trying to switch to an account on the login screen, I click one, and then the login input comes up but is for the wrong account. Typically what I have to do is then log into that account and try switching again, and it often works then.

Some more details:

- Typically the account that gets the focus on the login screen is my
  logged in administrator level account. The other account is not an admin.
- The administrator account has TouchID enabled while the other does not. Sometimes I login via TouchID, other times via password.
- 2019 Macbook Pro, 16 inch. I am on Sonoma 14.2.1.

I have just done a fresh MacOS install and the behavior continues.

My main question is if anyone else is experiencing this? My followup is if anyone has found a solution. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does Fast User Switching work correctly?

Comment: No, Fast User Switching has the same issue